# How to make specific app connect only when VPN active and make it's traffic only go with VPN tunnel

Tags: applications, vpn, background-process

I use VPN for some apps that's banned my country, but when the VPN stop sometimes that apps keep working in background so the servers discover my real country based ip then they block my account.. I need to know if i can find some way that prevent the app making background connection while the VPN tunnel not active.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: If your device is rooted you can use Afwall+. It allows blocking apps on mobile data, wifi, vpn, tor, etc. Disallow your apps on everything except the vpn in it. You have to enable vpn related setting in AFWall+ settings first.

Comment: Thanks for your useful advice